# LoadRunner: How to find a image size while replayin a script in C lang?

Tags: validation, loadrunner

I am running a script and a image is been downloaded to my browser's cache what if I want to check the image size,what function in C language i can use like I was using web_reg_find() for page validation whether a image is coming or not but what to do if I want to check its size also??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. For this to work you will need to record the page with the Recording Options:
    General > Recording > HTML-based script (HTML Advanced) > Non HTML-generated elements > Record in seperate steps

Also, for playback, make sure you aren't caching the resources or this will return '0'.

After you record the page locate the specific call for the image you are trying to report the size of and directly after that call add the function:
    web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_DOWNLOAD_SIZE);

This function returns an 'int', so you'll need to set up a variable to capture the value. It would look something like this:

```
Action()
{

    int imageSize;

    web_url("my_image.gif", 
        "URL=http://www.abc.com/images/my_image.gif", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "Resource=1", 
        "RecContentType=image/gif", 
        "Referer=http://www.abc.com/", 
        "Snapshot=t01.inf", 
        LAST);

    imageSize = web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_DOWNLOAD_SIZE);

}
```

There may be a different way to do this, but this has worked for me in the past.

Comment: thanx nathan.... thanx a lot. I found solution by your help... can u tell me one more thing, what if I am recording using url based script,can I perform image check there? If yes pls provide a short snipet

Comment: Yes, this will work with a URL based script and the code would look just the same as what I posted here for the image file request.

Comment: nathan when i am running this code in url based script it is giving error as no context for "HTML" :(